# adjust alignment of equation numbers with leqno

Tags: equations, numbering

I an using leqno and would like the equation numbers to be right justified relative to themselves. That is, I want all the digits in the ones column aligned, as they are when not using leqno. Below is what happen naturally, but I want the equation numbers to look like the enumerate numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\setcounter{enumi}{7}
   \item A
   \item B
   \item C
   \item D
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{equation}{7}
\begin{align}
   a=b\\
   b=c\\
   c=d\\
   d=e
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: What happens naturally]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first of all need to detach `\eqref` and the equation number making macros. Then you can redefine `\tagform@` to add a space as wide as a digit in case the equation number is less than 10.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@

\def\tagform@#1{%
  \ifx\theequation#1%
    \ifnum\value{equation}<10 \hphantom{0}\fi
  \fi
  \maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\setcounter{enumi}{7}
   \item A
   \item B
   \item C
   \item D
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{equation}{7}
\begin{gather}
   a=b\\
   b=c\\
   c=d\\
   d=e
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Cases where you use `\tag{...}` are not covered.

[image]

I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Why would you not do it?

Comment: @pgregory I wouldn't use `leqno` in the first place; I find the space before the number much worse than the missing alignment.