# Numbering in latex math document

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I am searching for the latex code wich produces every numbering before the theorems, propositions, lemmas, corollaries, remark and other simple math  equations like the following page of a book:
 [image]

In the above example the section is $1.3$ of chapter $1$. Also note that the numberings are in bold. Thanks for help.

Comment: You may find an answer at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems . If not, then ask. In that case please prepare a small complete document that we can copy and edit to show you what to do.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{(\thesection.\arabic{theorem})}` should work if the theorem counter is called `theorem`

Comment: using `amsthm`, `\swapnumbers` will move the numbers to the beginning of the theorem header.  after that, the suggestion by @ChristianHupfer for formatting the numbers is needed to put them in parentheses.  finally, fo number theorems consecutively with equations, the equation counter must be specified as the counter used for theorems.  consult the `amsthm` manual for `\swapnumber` and counter information: `texdoc amsthm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define suitably the theorem styles; also some trick has to be used for the equation number in boldface.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261647/4427
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@
% equation numbers are boldface
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\bfseries(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{main}% name
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\itshape}%  Body font (use \slshape if you want slanted type)
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {:}%         Punctuation after thm head
  { }%         Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {(\thmnumber{#2}) \thmname{#1}\thmnote{ {\normalfont(#3)}}}

\newtheoremstyle{maindefinition}% name
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\upshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {:}%         Punctuation after thm head
  { }%         Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {(\thmnumber{#2}) \thmname{#1}\thmnote{ {\normalfont(#3)}}}%


\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\theoremstyle{main}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{maindefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Exactness and intertwining}

\setcounter{section}{2}

\section{Test}

\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{definition}
We define \emph{something}
\end{definition}

Some text

\begin{proposition}
Some statement, an equation
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
and the end of the statement.
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}[With note]
Something
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you write two codes, maindefinition style and theorem style?

Comment: @dulalnarugopal Because, in my opinion, the text in a definition should be upright and not italics.

Comment: In the OP's screenshot, the theorem body font appears to be slanted-roman rather than italic.

Comment: @Mico That's an easy modification. With due respect to Donald Knuth, I dislike slanted type.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of slanted-roman type either. I just wanted to point out this minor detail. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You also can do that with `thmtools+amsthm` or with `nthm` alone. Concerning the equation numbers, it's the `leqno` option in the document class. Of course you should comment the part of the code you don't want to use:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}
\usepackage{xcharter}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%% Code for amsthm
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
%
\declaretheoremstyle[%
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
within=chapter, headformat = swapnumber, headpunct={:}, spaceabove = 8pt,spacebelow = 8pt]%
{mythm}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=mythm, %
preheadhook={\renewcommand \theTheorem{(\thesection.\arabic{Theorem})}}]{Theorem}

%%% Code for ntheorem
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand \theTheorem{(\thesection.\arabic{Theorem})} 
%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\section{A first section}
\begin{Theorem}
  The following assertion is true: %
  \begin{equation}\label{testeq}
    a = a\end{equation}
    \end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `thmtools` also works with `ntheorem`, but isn't required here. With `amsthm`, it eases the definition of new theorem styles.

Comment: I think the `Theorem` counter should be reset to `0` whenever `\section` is encountered. However, `\renewcommand \theTheorem{(\thesection.\arabic{Theorem})}` doesn't achieve this. Add something like `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{equation}{section} \makeatother`? Or, `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

Comment: @Mico: It is enough to code `within=section` using `thmtools`, and 
 `\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]` for the solution with `ntheorem`. But do you really think it's better to reset the theorem at sections? I didn't implement a common counter for theorems, definitions, remarks, &c.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure for the case at hand. In general, though, it seems to be more common practice to restart all subordinate counters every time `\section` is encountered than it is to let the counters be incremented monotonically.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here's a solution that uses the `ntheorem` package without other helper packages to define a custom look for the theorem headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % use a class that features chapter-level headers

%% Customize the appearance of equation numbers
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools} % for \newtagform and \usetagform macros
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtagform{bold}[\bfseries]{(}{)} % bold equation numbers
\usetagform{bold}
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}} % but non-bold cross-references


%% Customize the appearance of theorem-like environments
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mythm}%
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont(##2) ##1\theorem@separator]}%
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont(##2) ##1 [##3]\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother    
\theoremstyle{mythm}  % switch to the newly-defined theorem style
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{:}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[equation]
\newtheorem{prop}[equation]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{defn} 
A \emph{tame corestriction on $A$} (relative to $E/F$) is a \dots 
\end{defn}
\begin{prop} 
(i) Let $\psi_E$, $\psi_F$ be continuous additive characters \dots There exists a unique map $s\colon A\to B$ such that
\begin{equation} \label{eq:co}
\psi_A(ab)=\psi_B(s(a)b), \quad a\in A, b\in B.
\end{equation}
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) @Mico: For the equation number, wouldn't it be simpler to use the `\newtagform` command, from `mathtools`?

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks. Indeed, `\newtagform` is an option, say, `\newtagform{bold}[\bfseries]{(}{)}` followed by `\usetagform{bold}`. However, something still has to be done to avoid having cross-referenced equation numbers show up in bold.

Comment: `\renewcommand\eqref[1]{(\ref{#1})}` does the trick. Does it have any side effect?

Comment: @Bernard - Many thanks for this suggestion. I'll edit my answer to use the variant form `\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}`.