# \renewcommand{\theequation} and \renewcommand{\eqref} simultaneously

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, amsmath

I'm trying to change the output of equation numbering in the text and next to each equation simultaneously.
For example, for the 1st eqn, I would like to add "eqn 1" after the equation, and cite it in the text as "equation 1".

After reading a few posts, I tried using simultaneously:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{eqn \arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation \ref{#1}}
```

but using the `\renewcommand{\theequation}{eqn \arabic{equation}}` automatically adds the word `eqn` within the text, so I end up with an `equation eqn 1`.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{eqn \arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation \ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
This is an example \eqref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
y=2+4
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Basically what I would like to achieve is getting rid of the word `eqn` within the text, but keeping it after the equation. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is it really necessary to add `eqn` to an equation number -- I think equations are easily identifiable ...

Comment: unfortunately, this is a requirement for my manuscript

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to change `\tagform@` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261647/4427) and to use `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{(eqn #1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}

\begin{document}
This is an example \cref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
y=2+4
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the parentheses around the equation number in `\cref`, you need to set `\crefformat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{(eqn #1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\crefformat{equation}{equation~#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{Equation~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
This is an example \cref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
y=2+4
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty method: Gobbling some args from `\p@equation` which is responsible for the typesetting of references to an equation label:

Please note the `{}` around `eqn` -- it does no harm for the display at the number, but keeps the `eqn` text as a delimited token list and this can be 'gobbled' with moving arguments in the usage of `\gobblesomeargs` which drops the first argument (i.e. `eqn`) and prints only the 2nd one.

I suggest to keep the original `\eqref` as well and use another one, say `equref`.

My solution does not need an extra package however (apart from `amsmath`, which is also not necessary in if `\equref` is defined)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{eqn} \arabic{equation}}
%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation \ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\equref}[1]{equation \ref{#1}}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gobblesomeargs}[2]{#2}
\renewcommand{\p@equation}{\gobblesomeargs}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is an example \equref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
y=2+4
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the documentation of `mathtools` (which loads and extends `amsmath`)

> Altering the layout of equation numbers in amsmath is not very user
>   friendly (it involves a macro with three `@`'s in its name), so
>   `mathtools` provides an interface somewhat reminiscent of the page
>   style concept. This way you can define several different tag forms and
>   then choose the one you prefer.

Using this feature you can write

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{prefixed}[eqn ]{(}{)}
\usetagform{prefixed}

\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation \ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
This is an example \eqref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
y=2+4
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To reintroduce the standard version you can use

```
\usetagform{default}
```

Personal comment: instead of redefining `\eqref` I'd rather define something like `\Eqref`.