# How to keep equation number in a colored box in latex

Tags: amsmath, equation-number

I wish to customize the appearance of the equation number in latex. For example, see the below equation number is kept in a black box. How to achieve such a style?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag format in `amsmath` is

```latex
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
```

You can redefine it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}}
\makeatother
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
a+b&=c\\
b&=c+d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working and now it looks awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want that `\eqref` prints a black box with a white number inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261647/4427
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@

\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}%
}
\makeatother

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

We want to test some numbering
\begin{equation}\label{test}
1=1
\end{equation}
We see from~\eqref{test} that
\begin{align}
11&=1+10 \\
100&=50+50
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the redefinition of `\eqref` you'd get

[image]

If you really want `\eqref` to print the black box, I suggest to reduce its size so as to maintain line spacing correct: change the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` into

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\footnotesize\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely explained. Yeah, you are correct, I do not want `\eqref`. However, all your code worked well. Thank you.